# Can bootstrap-modal.js be used multiple times on same page dynamically?

Tags: php, javascript, popup, modal-dialog

I just found out about bootstrap-modal.js and love how the user can click a link, fill out a form on the pop up and then submit the change.  My question is this: can I have more than one instance of this on a page?

I have a list of names that I get from a database and display them on a page.  The user can add or delete them as they see fit.  I want to place a 'edit' link next to each name.  When the user clicks 'edit', it will load a popup and the name will appear in a text box to edit and then they can submit the change.  I can't figure out how to make this happen with modal.  When I implement it, all of the pop-up 'edit' links show the first name in the list and not the one I clicked on.  Is there a way to have a seperate popup for each name?  I did a bunch of searches and played around with the code(I don't really know anything about JS). and can't figure out how to make this happen.   I'm working with PHP on my site.
Any help is appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this I would have one modal and dynamically populate the name field and a hidden field that stores the ID for the form submission. Without seeing your code, something like this might work:

```
$('.modal-link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#form-modal').modal('show');
    $('#form-modal-name-field').val($(this).attr('data-name'));
    $('#form-modal-id-field').val($(this).attr('data-id'));
});
```

And then your HTML would be something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="1" data-name="Name1" class="modal-link">Edit Name 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-id="2" data-name="Name2" class="modal-link">Edit Name 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

This is rough, obviously, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: Great!  Just what I needed.  Took me a few minutes before I realized I had to put form-modal-name-field and id-field into the id part of the form inputs but once I did it worked perfectly.